# how to save separated parts (that come from k-means clustering) as different Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis, k-means

I used k-means clustering for a Dataframe that include salesNumber and Products. I used 3 means clustering. I can separate them and find centroids. But I also want to save my new 3 different divided datas as 3 different Dataframes. How can I do that?

df dataframe have 2 columns named SalesNumbers and ProductTypes.

```py
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df)
centroidsProduct = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroidsProduct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `labels_`:

```
df['ClusterID'] = kmeans.labels_
```